# mouseover not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Web development student, trying out a simple javascript mouseover.  This code is not working, any suggestions? EDIT: This has been edited and now is attempting to use hover instead.

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<title id="title"> Hybris Studios </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
// Rollover image
var homeBlack = new Image();
homeBlack.src = "http://hybrisstudios.com/Images/HomeBlack.png";
var oldSrc = $('.homeRed').attr('src');
$('.homeRed').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', homeBlack.src);
},
function() 
{
    $(this).attr('src', oldSrc);    
}); // end hover        
}); // end ready
</script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- Image Divs -->
<div class="homeRed">
<img src="Images/HomeRed.png"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<!-- CSS -->
<style type="text/css">

.homeRed {
    position : fixed;
    top  : 180px;
    left : 170px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you post the corresponding HTML?

Comment: Why do you need the `homeBlack` object?

Comment: It works for me. Show your HTML like chipChocolate.py asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly change the image `src` on mouseover or mouseleave without creating an `Image` object.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2oo13sh/)

#### HTML:

```
<img src="http://s25.postimg.org/e2wx0t4p7/chrome.png" />
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://s25.postimg.org/46vu15yx7/tardis.jpg');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://s25.postimg.org/e2wx0t4p7/chrome.png');
});
```

---

### ||---- Edit ----||

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4fspfbn/2/)

Your code fixed.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="homeRed">
    <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/e2wx0t4p7/chrome.png" />
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.homeRed').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', "http://s25.postimg.org/46vu15yx7/tardis.jpg");
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.homeRed {
    position : fixed;
    top : 180px;
    left : 170px;
}
```

Comment: Yea this looks easier thank you.  I would still like to figure out what I am doing wrong however.

Comment: @CodeDude12 -I've fixed your code, check out my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for showing me that way to do it, that looks more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are usind the wrong selector for your image. You select the div, not the img inside.

```
$('.homeRed')
```

The correct is:

```
$('.homeRed>img')
```

Whole line should be then:

```
$('.homeRed>img').hover(function() {
```

Comment: Nice, Mark as answer to your question? :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  It seems to work without the > as well like this $('.homeRed img')

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Rollover image
    var homeBlack = new Image();
    homeBlack.src = "Images/HomeBlack.png";  //this is a shorthand for the actual src
    $('.homeRed').hover(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', homeBlack.src);
    }); // end mouseover        
}); // end ready
```

Comment: `.hover()` is usually used when you want to specify two functions, one for entering, the other for leaving.

Comment: hmm for some reason that still is not working, I must be doing something else wrong within the code, I'll add the whole thing above.

Answer (score -3):

What about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Rollover image
    var homeBlack = new Image();
    homeBlack.src = "Images/HomeBlack.png";  //this is a shorthand for the actual src
    $('.homeRed').on('mouseover', function() {
         $(this).attr('src', homeBlack.src);
    }); // end mouseover        
});
```

Comment: @CodeDude, what is element '.homeRed', are you sure that it's possible to attach image there?

Comment: I added the html above